# Parsing Neo4j ExecutionResult dumptoString in java

Tags: java, neo4j

I am using Neo4j graph database and the Neo4j Cypher api of java to get the query result.A dump to string method will give the execution result in the string format.

```
  GraphDatabaseFactory graphDbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();

  GraphDatabaseService graphDb = graphDbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase("C:/TPNeo4jDB");

  ExecutionEngine execEngine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb);
  ExecutionResult execResult = execEngine.execute("MATCH (java:JAVA) RETURN java");
  String results = execResult.dumpToString();
  System.out.println(results);
```

The output string will look like this.

```
 +--------------------------+
 | a                        |
 +--------------------------+
 | Node[12]{type:"java 1"} |
 | Node[13]{type:"java 2"} |
 +--------------------------+
 2 rows
```

Is there any default apis to parse this in a generic way?

As per the answer i have done this

```
ExecutionResult execResult = execEngine.execute("MATCH (java:JAVA) RETURN java");
    Iterator<Node> n_column = execResult2.columnAs( "java" );
    for ( Node node : IteratorUtil.asIterable( n_column ) )
    {
        // note: we're grabbing the name property from the node,
        // not from the n.name in this case.
       String nodeResult = node + ": " + node.getProperty( "type" );
       System.out.println("noderesult :"+nodeResult);
    }
```

It gives result for the first value after which it throws exception.How to solve this?

```
noderesult :Node[12]: java 1

Jun 12, 2015 7:21:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path     [/BOSBOT] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is     org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException] with root cause
org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.assertInUnterminatedTransaction(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:71)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.getTopLevelTransactionBoundToThisThread(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:104)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.getKernelTransactionBoundToThisThread(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:111)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.get(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:64)
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase$8.statement(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:748)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.getProperty(NodeProxy.java:387)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
Iterator<Node> javaNodes = execResult.columnAs( "java");
for (Node node : IteratorUtil.asIterable(javaNodes))
{
    //do something with the node
}
```

More info including what to do when you have many columns is detailed in 
http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.8/tutorials-cypher-java.html

Update based on comment:

The Cypher query is `MATCH (java:Java) return java` so the column name will be java, and the value returned in that column is a `Node`.

If you wanted the type property, then the query would be `MATCH (java:Java) return java.type as type` and then you can do a `columnAs("type")`. The type of this column will now be a String.

Comment: execresult.columnAs() should be the column value right. here should it be 'type' instead of 'java'

Comment: Not really, your query says return java, so java is the column name. See update in answer

Comment: It is working for the first value after which an error is thrown. please see the updated answer.

Comment: The exception is the answer: NotInTransactionException. You need to wrap this all in a transaction. The docs illustrate this (the link I provided). You can also take a look at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.1.8/community/cypher/docs/cypher-docs/src/test/java/org/neo4j/cypher/example/JavaQuery.java which is referenced from that page.